# T4MVC is generating T4MVC.cs and T4MVC1.cs

Tags: c#, t4, t4mvc

- VS2017 15.4.1

  - ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3
  - [T4MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC) 4.0.0
  - [AutoT4MVC](http://bennor.github.io/AutoT4MVC/) 1.5.3
  - Resharper

I have been using T4MVC] for many months in this project without issue. However today each time I change a controller method it is generating two T4MVC files:

[image]

instead of updating T4MVC.cs which ultimately means the project wont't compile and I have to delete T4MVC1.cs.

Has anyone seen this behaviour or has some ideas of a fix?

Comment: Hi! what I usually do is delete the T4MVC.cs, T4MVC1.cs and all the generated.cs files and run the custom tool again.

Comment: I'm seeing this too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's the steps I do to fix it:

- Delete `T4MVC1.cs` file.
- Unload your project.
- Edit the `.csproj` file.
- Check the following tag:

  `<Compile Include="T4MVC.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>T4MVC.tt</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>`

  Make sure there's only one of these and it's `T4MVC.cs`. Remove `T4MVC1.cs` block if you have it.
- Check the following tag:

  `<None Include="T4MVC.tt">
      <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>T4MVC.cs</LastGenOutput>
  </None>`

  Make sure the `<LastGenOutput>` is `T4MVC.cs`. If not, edit it to be `T4MVC.cs`.
- Save the `.csproj` file.
- Reload the project.
- Rebuild
- Make sure to check in that code so won't cause any trouble in the future.

Comment: Awesome solution. Worked perfectly.

Comment: It worked for me, at T4MVC 4.2.4, using NET Framework 4.7.2